# Nodejs socket.io unhandled websocket unhandled error

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using socket.io-stream library to transfer files between 2 node servers.

Server A: (Send File)

```
  var clientIO = require('socket.io-client');
  var ss = require('socket.io-stream');

  var clientSocket= clientIO(`http://ServerB_Address`);
  clientSocket.on('error', (error) => {
      console.log(error);
  });

  var stream = ss.createStream({objectMode: true});
  ss(clientSocket).emit('send-file', stream, data);  
  var uploadedBytes = 0;
  var from = 0;
  var reader = fs.createReadStream(filePath, {start: from});
  reader.pipe(stream)
   .on('error', (error) => {
       console.log(error);
   })
   .on('data', (chunk) => {
       uploadedBytes += Buffer.byteLength(chunk);                                
   });
```

Server B: (Receive File)

```
 var fs = require('fs');
    var io = require('socket.io')(http);
    var ss = require('socket.io-stream');

    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        // listen to send file
        ss(socket).on('send-mail', (stream, data) => {
            console.log(`*** Begin receive file`);

            var writer = fs.createWriteStream(downloadPath, {flags: 'a'});
            stream.pipe(writer);

            var size = 0;
            stream.on('data', (chunk) => {
                size += chunk.length;
                console.log(`*** Receive ${size} from mail`);
            });

            stream.on('end', () => {
                console.log(`*** End file`);
            });

            stream.on('error', (error) => {
                console.log(`*** Error when receiving file`);
                console.log(error);
            });
        });
    });
```

It works fine, but when transferring file if the second node server is stopped, the app in the other server crashed and an unhandled error event was thrown

[image]

Please can anyone tell me how can I catch this error? And if there is a better way to transfer files between node servers?

Comment: Haven't worked with file transfers on socket.io but it may be helpful to provide what line of code corresponds to line 183 in events.js

Comment: I don't know what line of code causes this error event.js is not in my code I think it is in node_modules